1D Heat Equation with First-order Boundary Conditions
I am trying to solve a heat equation of the following form
$$  \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\qquad t > 0,\quad 0 < x < 1 $$
The boundary conditions are
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle k\,\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(1, t) & \displaystyle = & \displaystyle u(1, t)
\\[1mm] \displaystyle u(0, t) & \displaystyle = & \displaystyle 0
\end{array}\right.
$$
and the initial condition is given by $u(x, 0) = f(x)$.

I am interested in the possible choices for $k$ such that
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} u(x, t) = 0,
$$
that is, the solution decays to $0$ as time progresses.
Here's what I got so far:

Apply separation of variables by assuming
$u = X(x)T(t)$. Then, we immediately have
$$
\frac{X''}{X} = \frac{T'}{T} = -\lambda \implies X(x) = b\sin(\sqrt{\lambda} x), \; T(t) = ce^{-\lambda t}
$$
where $X(x)$ has no $\cos$ term because of the condition $u(0, t) = 0$.
I tried to apply the first boundary condition to the $X$ eigenvalue problem, but all I managed to find is
$$
k\sqrt{\lambda}\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}) = \sin(\sqrt{\lambda})
$$
which cannot be solved to find eigenvalues and eigenfunctions.



How should I proceed ?.

Only certain $\lambda$s will work. Find those first.

@Aruralreader I tried a few typical choices like $\sqrt{\lambda} = 0, n\pi, (n + 1/2)\pi$. None of them seem to solve this trancendental equation. Do you mind giving a hint?

Zeros of $kz\cos z - \sin z$.

There are no explicit formulas for the roots of this transcendental equation but you can prove there is a countable sequence of them going to $\infty$

if we have a spectrum of eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ and two sets of functions $X_n(x)$ and $T_n(t)$ obeying
$$X_n^{''}=-\lambda_nX_n \text{ and } T_n^{'}=-\lambda_nT_n$$
then $$u(x, t)=\sum_n a_nX_n(x)T_n(t)$$
is a solution to the original p.d.e.

We choose the solution approach
$$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\cdot e^{-\lambda_n^2 t}\cdot \sin(\lambda_n x)$$
with
$$a_n=\frac{\int_0^1 f(x)\cdot \sin(\lambda_n x)\; dx}{\int_0^1 \sin^2(\lambda_n x)\; dx}=\frac{\int_0^1 f(x)\cdot \sin(\lambda_n x)\; dx}{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sin(2\lambda_n)}{4\lambda_n}}$$
$\lambda_n$ must satisfy
$$k \lambda_n\cdot \cos(\lambda_n)=\sin(\lambda_n)$$
where $\lambda_n$ is the $n^{th}$ root of the equation und can be computed numerically.
Plot example with $f(x)=u(x)-u(x-\frac{1}{2}),\; k=-2$:

